# Xamarin Forms Deep Linking

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, oauth, strava

I have tried getting Xamarin Forms deep linking to work by following the example in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/deep-linking.

It tells me I must have a version of my app live on Google Play, and I must also have a companion website registered with Google.
How am I supposed to test, develop, and debug my app if it has to already be published for this to work?

Note that I don't want app indexing, I just want deep linking. This all seems a bit involved - why do I even need a website?

All I basically want to do is authenticate the user to Strava via OAuth and handle the redirect URI.

Is there a simple example of how to get just deep linking to work, in such a way as it could handle the redirect URI from Strava?

Comment: I don't think Deep Linking is what you want if you're just trying to use OAuth.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/oauth

Comment: That's just for authenticating to google though isn't it? Please point out where in that documentation I put the strava URL if you think otherwise.

Comment: That would be the AuthorizeUrl - the example uses Google but any OAuth provider should work

Comment: i don't think that's going to work. Specifically, the bit that says "Client ID – this identifies the client that is making the request, and can be retrieved from the project in the Google API Console.
Client Secret – this should be null or string.Empty" seems to indicate that this documentation is specific to Google. Strava requires you to pass the client secret on what those docs list as 'Step 3: The application exchanges the authorization code for an access token from the identity provider'. So where do I specify it if it should be null or empty?

Comment: And surely I still need deep linking to work even if I use that library - because the OAuth provider just redirects to a URL, so I still need deep linking to work even if Xamarin.Auth 'handles' (or tries to handle) the return URL? I think my problem is (or was) at a lower level than that library deals with - it's about how to get the Android system to invoke my app for a certain URL, not about how to get my app to deal with the URL once that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have discovered a solution that works which is to simply put an IntentFilter on the MainActivity of my app:

```
[IntentFilter(
    new[] { Intent.ActionView },
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataSchemes = new[] { "<my package name>" },
    DataHosts = new[] { "redirect.authorize.strava.<my package name>" }
    )]
```

When I do this, it successfully calls `OnAppLinkRequestReceived` when strava fires the redirect URL with the deep link.

Wouldn't have known that from any docs though....